# Saving commands in a user-created shell to a file before executing execvp in C

Tags: c, file, save, command, execvp

I made a shell and everything works great except I can't seem to save executable commands in a history file. However, all the invalids commands get saved.

Here is the child portion:

```
// child
} else if (pid == 0){
    for (int i = 0; i < len_of_arguments; i++){
        if ( arguments[i + 1] == NULL ){
            fprintf(Shell_hist, "%s", arguments[i]);
        } else {
            fprintf(Shell_hist, "%s ", arguments[i]);
        }
    }
    fprintf(Shell_hist, "\n");

    execvp(arguments[0], arguments);
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: command does not exist.\n");

    exit(SUCCESS);
```

Can someone please explain to me why the for loop won't run with successful executables? Shouldn't the for loop always execute before the execvp()?

Comment: `fflush()` the output file before calling `execvp()`.  When you call `execvp()`, you lose whatever remains buffered in memory of what you tried to write to the file.

Comment: You probably don't want the shell history file open in the child process; you should close it (and any other unnecessary files) before the `execvp()`.  Closing the file also flushes pending contents.  You should aim to ensure that there's no pending standard output before you run the command too.  Note that exiting with status EXIT_SUCCESS after failing to execute a command is a gross abuse of the exit status.  It should be EXIT_FAILURE at least, or possibly more sensitive than that.  POSIX reserves various statuses (126, 127) for reporting different problems.